# Не корректно работает код. Вызов функции при проверке условия

Tags: javascript

Проблема заключается в том что при проверке условия в if я вызываю функцию lieToEmployer которая меняет значения объекта employee. И в итоге функция hireNewEmployee пишет что я не нанят на работу из-за возраста хотя значение возраст(>=25) позволяет принять меня на работу.

```js
const filters = {
    age:       (a) => a >= 25,
    education: (a) => a === 'higher',
    experience:(a) => a >= 1,
};
const employee = {};
const defaultDescriptors = {
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
};
Object.defineProperties(employee, {
    name: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 'Dmitriy',
        writable: false
    },
    age: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 21
    },
    education: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 'middle'
    },
    experience: {
        ...defaultDescriptors,
        value: 0
    }
})
function hireNewEmployee (employee,filters) {
    const reasons = [];
    Object.entries(filters).forEach(([name,func]) => {
        if (func(employee[name]) === false) {
            function lieToEmployer (employee) {
                return Object.defineProperties(employee, {
                    age: {
                        value: 27
                    },
                    education: {
                        value: 'higher'
                    },
                    experience: {
                        value: 7
                    }
                });
            }
            lieToEmployer(employee);
            reasons.push(name);
        }
    });
    return reasons.length
        ? `Not hired: sorry we cannot hire you. Here is why: ${reasons.join(', ')}`
        : 'You are Hired! Congrats!';
}
console.log(hireNewEmployee(employee,filters));
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой для нахождения участка кода с некорректной логикой

Comment: Зачем вы городите столько кода для такой простой задачи? Например есть какая-та супер важная причина почему вы используете `Object.defineProperties`?

Comment: @EzioMercer да мне по заданию надо создать объект с помощью Object.defineProperties

Comment: Что у вас происходит в `if`?

Comment: @EzioMercer если метод в объекте filters возвращает false то, мы запушиваем метод который ===false из объекта filters в массив reasons также  мы вызываем функцию lieToEmployer которая меняет значения в объекте employee на новые.

Comment: Но вы это делаете после того как уже добавили причину для отказа. Не по коду, а по смыслу имею ввиду. То что вы подменяете значения никак не влияют на текущую итерацию

Comment: @EzioMercer я предполагаю что функция lieToEmployer не успевает менять значения объекта employee на новые, таким образом функция hireNewEmployee работает со старыми значениями объекта employee. Как решить данную проблему не понимаю

Comment: @EzioMercer мне по заданию надо во время первой проверки вызывать функцию lieToEmployer которая меняет значения в объекте employee.

Comment: Нет, все всё успевают. Вы выстраиваете порядок действий неприавильно. То что вы меняете значения у самого объекта `employee` никак не меняет результат проверки в `if`

Comment: Вы можете свою ф-ию просто вынести за `if` и вызывать до него, а не внутри

Comment: @EzioMercer так как вы посоветовали вынести за if работает. Но проблема в том что надо по заданию вызывать функцию lieToEmployer во время проверки. Так бы я давно бы вынес ее

Comment: Ну тогда продублируйте проверку после вызова функции и если там тоже проверка не будет пройдена, то добавляйте в своей массив причину